# Fluent NHibernate - ValidationException Entity does not have an Id mapped

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Getting following error while generating scema with FNH:

```
ValidationException: The Entity 'TemplateStatusInfo' dows not have an Id mapped.
```

Class mapping defined as below:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class Template
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual TemplateStatusInfo TemplateStatus { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TemplateStatusInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<string> ValidCodes { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string TemplateError { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class TemplateMap : ClassMap<Template>
{
    public const string TableName = "Template";

    public TemplateMap()
    {
        Table(TableName);
        Id(x => x.Id).UnsavedValue(null).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Title).Not.Nullable().Length(150);          
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("type");
    }
}

public class TemplateStatusInfoMap : ClassMap<TemplateStatusInfo>
{
    public TemplateStatusInfoMap()
    {
        Table(TemplateMap.TableName);

        HasMany(x => x.ValidCodes).Table("TemplateValidCodes").KeyColumn("Id").Element("CodeName").AsSet().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        Map(x => x.TemplateError).Length(1000);
    }
}
```

It should result in two tables "Template"(with columns- Id, Title, TemplateError) and child table "TemplateValidCodes"(with columns- Id, CodeName).

Can anyone please guide how can I map Id for TemplateStatusInfo here (which will essentially be Template.Id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to have a many (ValidCodes ) one (TemplateStatusInfo) association but TemplateStatusInfo doesn't have an id, so how can the database relate these peices of information?  Also you did not map TemplateStatus in the Template mapping.

I think your data structure needs a bit of a rethink.

Probably TemplateStatusInfo should be mapped as a component of Template, rather than being a separate entity.

Try this:

```
public class TemplateMap : ClassMap<Template>
{
    public const string TableName = "Template";

    public TemplateMap()
    {
        Table(TableName);
        Id(x => x.Id).UnsavedValue(null).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Title).Not.Nullable().Length(150);
        Component(x => x.TemplateStatus, TemplateStatusInfoComponentMap.Map);          
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("type");
    }
}

public class TemplateStatusInfoComponentMap
    {
        public static void Map(ComponentPart<TemplateStatusInfo> part)
        {
           part.HasMany(x => x.ValidCodes).Table("TemplateValidCodes").KeyColumn("Id").Element("CodeName").AsSet().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
           part.Map(x => x.TemplateError).Length(1000);
        }
    }
```